# Create instance of model from method

Tags: django, django-models

I'm new in Django, got a problem.
I have a method in Commodity Model:

```
@transaction.atomic
def payment(self):
    if self.owner.balance > self.price and self.active is False:
        self.act_time_till = now() + timedelta(days=1)
        self.owner.balance -= self.price
        # here i need to create a new Invoice object
        self.save()
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

And I have a different model - Invoice:

```
class Invoice(models.Model):
    commodity = models.ForeignKey(Commodity, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
    paid_till = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    value = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2, blank=False, null=False)
```

How can I create an instance of Invoice every time I make payment?
Thanks!

Comment: you can just create an instance by calling  `Invoice.objects.create(**data)`, also you could use this anywhere you needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just call inside this method.

```
@transaction.atomic
def payment(self):
   if self.owner.balance > self.price and self.active is False:
     self.act_time_till = now() + timedelta(days=1)
     self.owner.balance -= self.price
     # here i need to create a new Invoice object
     self.save()
     ## After this line you can create invoice object instance
     Invoice.objects.create(commodity=self, paid_till=self.act_paid_till, value=self.price)  
    return True
   else:
     return False
```

Comment: Thanks! It was PyCharm marked this as error. I had a trouble with field type, but i thought I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
# considering that you have invoice object available in the module. If not then you
# need to import it first.
Invoice.objects.create(commodity=self, paid_till=self.act_paid_till, value=self.price)
```